# How to make an SQL query for duplicates records?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I need to perform an SQL query to create a table which lists Quizzes with the same name. This is the query code I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.name, a.id FROM tests a 
        INNER JOIN tests b 
        ON a.tests = b.tests WHERE a.id <> b.id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

However I'm not getting any results - I've made sure to manually check the database and there are definitely duplicates. Any ideas?

Comment: What **RDBMS** and which version? And how are you rows duplicate - which columns must match for two rows to be considered duplicate? All of them? - just use `DISTINCT` to get rid of duplicates!

Comment: Your query does not check for duplicates. Your clause is a.id<>b.id. This means you are looking for records that do NOT match the ID. Nothing in your query looks for the same name. So, you probbaly meant it to be (a.name=b.name AND a.id=b.id) I'd suggest JW's method of grouping by name and finding those that have a count(*) > 1

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what RDBMS is, and yes it's MySQL sorry. I don't want to remove duplicates, just need to identify the rows with duplicate 'name' column so I can rename them as I see fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simpliest way is to grouped then and filter it using `HAVING`

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tests
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This shows the tests names once - is there a way to modify it so that it will actually show how many rows have the same name? So for example, we have several tests with the name "Proteins", I need it to display exactly how many (with the id for each one)